# Looping in Matlab to batch process Excel files

Tags: excel, matlab

I know how to read in multiple Excel files, but am struggling to conduct the same analysis on all of those files. The analysis requires I average some values in different columns, then print those average values to a separate Excel sheet. I can do this with one Excel file, but have trouble figuring out how to print each average value in a different row in the output Excel file. Here is the code I have that works for one file (reads it, averages values in column 4, then prints to a separate Excel file):

```
 data = xlsread('test_1.xlsx');
 average_values_1 = data(:,4);
 a = [average_values_1];
 data_cells = num2cell(a);
 column_header ={'Average Value 1'};
 row_header(1,1) ={'File 1'}
 output = [{' '} column_header; row_header data_cells];
 xlswrite('Test Averages.xls', output);
```

How might I do this over and over again while printing values from each file in the output file as its own table? I suspect a nested loop is in my future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For large numbers k in the loop, using xlswrite will be very time inefficient as there is a significant degree of overhead where xlswrite has to invoke the matlab VBA server, open excel, and subsequently close the excel file. Perhaps consider storing the entire list of averages into a matrix/vector and writing them all in 1 step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will eventually use this with large numbers of Excel files, so I will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example of what you possibly want to do with [**`xlswrite`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)<sup>[‍1]</sup>:

```
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';  % Filename to save average values in
for k = 1:10                 % Looping for 10 iterations
    sheet = 2;               % Selecting sheet2
    Avg = randi([1 10],1,1); % Generating a random average each time the loop is run
    xlRange = char(64+k);    % 65 is the ASCII value of A
    xlswrite(filename,Avg,sheet,xlRange); % Writing the excel file
end
```

This code gives the following output <sup>[‍2]</sup> :

[image: output1]

<sup>*Fig.1: Values are saved in a single row of excel file*</sup>

If you want to get the output in a single column then use this `xlRange = ['A',num2str(k)];` instead. It'll give you the following output <sup>[‍2]</sup> :

[image: output2]

<sup>*Fig.2: Values are saved in a single column of excel file*</sup>

---

<sup>[‍1]: Read the documentation of [**`xlswrite`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) for more details.</sup>

<sup>[‍2]: Output values may vary since random integers are generated.</sup>

Comment: This is useful. To further add to my question, how might I specify that on the first iteration of the loop, I want the values to be stored in the first row, then the second row for the second iteration and so on? I think that this in conjunction with your answer will help me solve my problem.

Comment: @Mickey e.g, if you want to save , say,  4 numbers on every iteration, row by row then change  `xlRange` to this:  `xlRange = ['A',num2str(k),':', 'D',num2str(k)];`